# Magento Admin Panel error message: Fatal error: spl_autoload() [<a href='function.spl-autoload'>function.spl-autoload</a>]:

Tags: magento

When attempting to login to the Magento admin panel, I am faced with the error message below. I could login fine yesterday and made no changes, so cannot understand why an error has occurred and am not sure how to resolve this one.

> Fatal error: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Class
>   Zend_Log_Exception could not be loaded in
>   /homepages/34/d502468010/htdocs/lib/Zend/Log/Writer/Stream.php on line
>   135

Comment: try to clear your `var/session` and `cache`

Comment: what are your permissions on `var/log` and the files in it? it's feasible that this could be caused by a permissions error while trying to write a log file